# Aligning div elements in columns next to each other using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm currently building a chat web app and have been working on the frontend for some time now. I just came across flexbox because I wanted to know how to center div elements but I can't figure out how I can center it the way I want it to be. My goal is to **move the 2 elements with the blue background to the center, right below the "CHAT" heading, so they are also on the same level as the 2 elements marked green (postion of black square)**. The problem that I have here, is that I'm trying to use both column and row direction because the 2 elements in  the green and blue boxes are aligned vertically and both boxes should be aligned horizontally next to each other. I have tried putting the green and blue elements in one flex container each and then wrapping one container around, which aligns them horizontally, but it also didn't have the result I wanted and I think there are better ways of doing it. Thanks for helping me!
[image]

```html
 <div class="container-2">

            <div class="room-section" id="display-room">
                {{room}}
            </div>

            <div class="room-section">
                <nav id="sidebar">
                    <h4>Rooms</h4>
                    {% for room in rooms %}
                        <button id="{{ room|title }}" class="select-room">{{ room|title }}</button>
                    {% endfor %}
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="message-section" id="display-message-section"></div>

            <div class="input-section" id="input-area">
                <input type="text" id="user_message" placeholder="Type message..." autocomplete="off">
                <button type="button" id="send_message">SEND</button>
            </div>

        </div>
```

```
.container-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example with compiled code please?

Answer (score 0):

Usr flex-direction: row to display it sidewise

Comment: This would place all the elements in a row which is not what I want. The both elements in the green and blue marked div's are aligned vertically and I want them to stay like that, so that only the 2 elements from the blue div are on the same level as the green one and in the center, but still aligned vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-2 {
    display: row; //alternatively just remove this, the default is row for flex direction
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that there is something like `display: row;`

Comment: Sorry about that, i meant "Flex-direction: row"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
.container-2 {
display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between;//or you can check the other properties of justify-content
}
```

But here you may have some problems because of this line:

```
<div class="room-section" id="display-room">
                {{room}}
            </div>

            <div class="room-section">
                <nav id="sidebar">
                    <h4>Rooms</h4>
                    {% for room in rooms %}
                        <button id="{{ room|title }}" class="select-room">{{ room|title }}</button>
                    {% endfor %}
                </nav>
            </div>
```

What you may need to do is put both of them to the same parent div.